# My maven module cannot be built and I don´t understand why

Tags: maven, pom.xml, parent-pom

I am learning Maven and trying to set up a simple project. I would like this structure:

```
-myproject
  -myproject-ear
  -myproject-service
    -webservice
  -myproject-ejb
```

**EDIT 1**
Solved. New problem in edit 2 below.

**EDIT 2**
I can compile and deploy my EAR file when I don´t have support for JavaEE. But when I add support for JavaEE I get some errors.
The root pom.xml (myproject) is as follows:

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
 <project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
 xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0
    http://maven.apache.org/maven-v4_0_0.xsd">

<modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
<groupId>myproject</groupId>
<artifactId>myproject</artifactId>
<packaging>pom</packaging>
<version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
<name>myproject</name>
<url>http://maven.apache.org</url>

<modules>
    <module>myproject-ejb</module>
    <module>myproject-service</module>
    <module>myproject-ear</module>
</modules>

<repositories>
    <repository>
        <id>jboss</id>
        <url>http://repository.jboss.org/maven2/</url>
    </repository>
</repositories>

<dependencyManagement>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.jboss.spec</groupId>
            <artifactId>jboss-javaee-6.0</artifactId>
            <version>3.0.2.Final</version>
            <scope>provided</scope>
            <type>pom</type>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
            <artifactId>hibernate-entitymanager</artifactId>
            <version>4.2.0.Final</version>
            <scope>provided</scope>
            <type>pom</type>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
            <artifactId>hibernate-core</artifactId>
            <version>4.2.0.Final</version>
            <scope>provided</scope>
            <type>pom</type>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-ejb-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>2.3</version>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-jar-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>2.3.2</version>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-war-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>2.3</version>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-ear-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>2.8</version>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>3.1</version>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-assembly-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>2.4</version>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-resources-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>2.4.3</version>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
</dependencyManagement>

<build>
    <pluginManagement>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-jar-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.3.2</version>
                <configuration>
                    <archive>
                        <addMavenDescriptor>false</addMavenDescriptor>
                    </archive>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-ejb-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.3</version>
                <configuration>
                    <ejbVersion>3.0</ejbVersion>
                    <archive>
                        <addMavenDescriptor>false</addMavenDescriptor>
                    </archive>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-ear-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.8</version>
                <configuration>
                    <archive>
                        <addMavenDescriptor>false</addMavenDescriptor>
                    </archive>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-war-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.1.1</version>
                <configuration>
                    <archive>
                        <addMavenDescriptor>false</addMavenDescriptor>
                    </archive>
                    <failOnMissingWebXml>false</failOnMissingWebXml>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-release-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.0</version>
                <configuration>
                    <remoteTagging>true</remoteTagging>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.1</version>
                <configuration>
                    <remoteTagging>true</remoteTagging>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-assembly-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.4</version>
                <configuration>
                    <remoteTagging>true</remoteTagging>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </pluginManagement>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
            <configuration>
                <source>1.7</source>
                <target>1.7</target>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>
```

And the pom.xml for the `myproject-ejb` looks like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<project
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd"
    xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <parent>
        <groupId>myproject</groupId>
        <artifactId>myproject</artifactId>
        <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
    </parent>
    <groupId>myproject</groupId>
    <artifactId>myproject-ejb</artifactId>
    <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <name>myproject-ejb</name>
    <packaging>ejb</packaging>
    <url>http://maven.apache.org</url>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
            <artifactId>hibernate-core</artifactId>
            <version>4.2.0.Final</version>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
</project>
```

If I create an interface, like

```
package org.myproject.ejb.customer;

import javax.ejb.Remote;

@Remote
public interface TestBean {
    public void createSomethingOnDatabase();
}
```

then the `javax.ejb.*` package cannot be found and `mvn clean install` fails. Have I missed something in my pom.xml for `myproject-ejb`?

**EDIT 3** 
This is what I get if I add the dependency for jboss-javaee-6.0 (including the version) in myproject-ejb:

```
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal on project myproject-ejb: Could not resolve dependencies for project myproject:myproject-ejb:ejb:1.0-SNAPSHOT: The following artifacts could not be resolved: org.jboss.spec:jboss-javaee-6.0:jar:3.0.2.Final, xalan:xalan:jar:2.7.1.jbossorg-2: Could not find artifact org.jboss.spec:jboss-javaee-6.0:jar:3.0.2.Final in central (http://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2) -> [Help 1]
```

Comment: If the webservice in a folder under myproject-service located ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Dependencies are matched against those in dependency management using `groupId`, `artifactId`, `type` and `classifier`. Default value for `type` is `jar` and for `classifier` it's `null`.

The dependency in `myproject-ejb` should therefore be:

```
<dependency>
  <groupId>org.jboss.spec</groupId>
  <artifactId>jboss-javaee-6.0</artifactId>
  <type>pom</type>
</dependency>
```

(regarding `EDIT 3`)

Answer (score 2):

Based on what i can see in the output you didn't defined a dependency on the webservice in your ear module, cause the webservice must be build before the ear module.

Comment: Thanks for you answer! I reordered the modules so that the EAR is built after the webservice. Look at my changes above. Any suggestions on what I have done wrong?

Comment: The reordering is not enough, cause the order will be calculated by the reactor in Maven which will do that based on the dependency tree between the modules. And it looks that your tree is not ok. Can you make a sample project which contains all modules an put that on github etc. to get a better view on the project? Or can you post the full pom files and the exact folder strcuture?

Comment: Hello again! I updated my previous post with two of the pom´s. Now I can build the project, but if I create a simple java class in `myproject-ejb` and import `java.ejb` package, the package cannot be found. Why?

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you are trying to depend on `<artifactId>myproject-webservice</artifactId>`but your module is `myproject-service`

Also, should `myproject-service` be packaged as a jar rather than a war?  Typically if a project is used as a dependency by another project, it will be packaged as a jar. See [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5597327/maven-war-dependency-cannot-resolve-package) for some notes.

Comment: Hello! `myproject-service` is the parent of `myproject-service-webservice`. I just succeeded with the compilation but now I cannot make use of `java.ejb` package in my `myproject-ejb` module since the package cannot be found in java code. Look at my previous post for further details.

Answer (score 1):

You can add the JavaEE dependency in the `myproject-ejb`.

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.jboss.spec</groupId>
        <artifactId>jboss-javaee-6.0</artifactId>
        <version>3.0.2.Final</version>
    </dependency>
```

**Regarding your third update to the question:**

Here is the dependency I use for `javax.ejb.Remote` :

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>javax</groupId>
    <artifactId>javaee-api</artifactId>
    <version>6.0</version>
    <scope>provided</scope>
</dependency>
```

You may use it instead of `org.jboss.spec`.

Comment: I tried that but then it says: `The project myproject:myproject-ejb:1.0-SNAPSHOT (/Users/myuser/Documents/myproject/myprojects-ejb/pom.xml) has 1 error
'dependencies.dependency.version' for org.jboss.spec:jboss-javaee-6.0:jar is missing. @ line 25, column 14`

Comment: Ok then, you can add the version as well. I updated the answer to reflect that.

Comment: I don´t know if something in the maven repository is broken. I have also tested to include the version number but that generates another error. Look at my `EDIT 3` in my original post.

Comment: That made the compilation but the deployment on my JBoss 7.1.1 doesn´t seem to work without the org.jboss.spec javaee-6.0 package. Why use jboss-javaee-6.0 and not javax javaee-api? What´s the difference?

Comment: Regarding the difference between modules: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15518148/maven-javaee-api-vs-jboss-javaee-6-0 . But I think Franta may have a better answer for your original problem.

Answer (score 0):

For your EDIT 3 problem: you need to include repository into your parent pom or pom:

```
<repositories>
    <repository>
        <id>jboss-repo</id>
        <name>jboss-repo</name>
        <url>https://repository.jboss.org/nexus/content/repositories/thirdparty-releases</url>
    </repository>
</repositories>
```

Then force to update your maven dependencies.

```
mvn clean install -U
```